# How to make bindable property in Actionscript Project

Tags: data-binding, actionscript, binding

I have seen a lot of codes regarding how to bind property in Flex project. Such as this code in Flex Help:
                var watcherSetter:ChangeWatcher = 
                    BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateMyString, myTI, "text");

However, I am creating Actionscript class within Actionscript Project, and I cannot import mx.binding.utils.* into my project. How could I make this works when Actionscript project cannot see this package? Is there any other way to makes property of different object bind together in Actionscript project?

Answer (score 1):

which IDE are you using?

please note, you can always manually import the classes by simply adding a classpath pointing to the flex framework sources with the SDK.

also, do not forget to declare the properties as bindable using the according metatag.

Comment: I don't think the metatag works with the Flash compiler, if that's what he's using.

Comment: @jonathanasdf: this rather sounds like a pure ActionScript project in FD, FDT or Flex Builder.

Comment: I already add source path to where the Adobe Flash Builder 4 was installed, it still didn't work. Or, may be I didn't know exactly where this package has been kept?

Comment: @ohm: please look in %FLEX_SDK_ROOT%/frameworks/projects/framework/src